# Is it possible to rely on computed-properties-mapped-getter-values inside a created block in a Vue instance?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuex

Would like to know if - by the time - accessing a computed property which get its value from the store - inside a created block - I can be sure that the computed value is already initiated.

```
async created(){
  !this.apps.length && await this.loadApps();
},
computed: {
  ...mapGetters('apps-store', ['apps']),
},
```

Answer (score 0):

[Hooks are just functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65639724/how-to-use-async-await-in-vue-lifecycle-hooks-with-vuex) that get fired on proper times - they are announcement not middleware. So, async hook does not wait to being fulfilled. You should provide a default value for the app getter __ either in the getter function or its state.