# vue3 App.vue mounted not running first before a compoment View being created

Tags: axios, vuejs3, vue-cli

I created FunA in App.vue Mounted(). I created FunB in HomeView.vue Mounted().
I go to HomeView Page and Refresh the page, FunB run before FunA. 
My Question is isn't App.vue Stuff run first before the compoment stuff ? I created FunC in App.vue beforeCreate(), and go back HomeView page and refresh again. I saw that Fun B still run before FunC and FunA.
If I am using FunA as a global function to setup Axios Auth Headers, all compoment Mounted functions with Axios get will return 403 error.
All stuff is working correctly if I enter the view by router-view.

What should I do except adding the auth headers to all Axios Request.

App.vue

```
async mounted() {
        await this.getServerTokenAuth()
    },
    methods: {
        async getServerTokenAuth(){
            await this.$mainApi.post('api/auth/', {
                "username": "qweqwe",
                "password": "qweqweqwe"
            })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response.data.token)
                    this.$store.commit("setServerToken")
                    this.$mainApi.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Token " + response.data.token;
                    this.$mainApi.defaults.headers.common['Accept-Language'] = this.$store.state.language;

                    if(this.$store.state.isAuthenticated === true){
                        this.$mainApi.defaults.headers.common['CUSTOM_HEADERS'] = "qweqweqwe";
                        console.log("User Data Added to Headers")
                    }
                })
        },
```

HomeView

```
 async mounted() {
    await this.getBackendData() // return 403 error
},
    methods: {
        async getBackendData(){
            // try to console log the Auth Headers, return undefined
            await this.$mainApi.get('api/product/list/')
                .then(response => {
                    if(response.data.status === 80){
                        this.tabulator.setData(response.data.details)
                        this.totalProduct = response.data.details.length
                    }
                })
        }
    },
```

Comment: Hi, 10 lines of code is better than 10 of text. Please provide a [repro].

Answer (score 1):

I found the method to solve.
[How to use async/await in vue lifecycle hooks with vuex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65639724/how-to-use-async-await-in-vue-lifecycle-hooks-with-vuex)

Just Add a flag in App.vue's api Function.

```
async getServerTokenAuth(){
            await this.$mainApi.post('api/auth/', {
                "username": "qweqwe",
                "password": "qweqwe"
            })
                .then(response => {
                        ...
            this.doneApiSetting = true // ADD THIS
```

In App.vue Template

```
<template>
    
    // Add a Flag here, so this part will run after the API setting is complete
    <div class="main" v-if="doneApiSetting">
        <router-view/>
    </div>

</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using [AwaitLock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/await-lock) is a solution in this case. The `HomeView` mounted hook will be locked until the `App` mounted hook is done.

Comment: Sorry, i am not very understand where should i put this lock in. I tried on App.vue Mounted but the problem is still happening.

Comment: You have to create an AwaitLock instance in the App component and provide it to the HomeView component (use provide + inject)). 
I think the correct flow is: 
1. Create AwaitLock instance in the App component:
`const lock = new AwaitLock()`
2. Acquire the lock
`lock.tryAcquire()`
3. Provide the lock instance
4. Inject the lock in "HomeView" component
5. When the App mounted hook finished, release the lock.
6. In HomeView mounted hook, try to acquire the lock
await lock.acquireAsync()
// mounted hooks logics